# Cant make a gui icon to start a terminal command

Tags: gui

I want to make a link on my desktop that just executes a simple Linux command. When I search the internet all I find are ways to start a GUI interface from within a shell.

Is there a tool to make such a link?

Comment: Search for how to create a .desktop file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

put this in a file and fill it out

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open 
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=comand_to_run
Icon=/path/to/icon
Name=name
Type=Application
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard Ubuntu, such graphical tool is not available. However, you can install and use Alacarte to edit and create new items in the application overview without the need to create or edit the corresponding `.desktop` files yourself. Search for "alacarte" or "main menu" in the activities overview to find and launch the tool.

That tool will create the launcher in your `.local/share/applications` menu.

- *Copy* the corresponding file over to your desktop to have it on the desktop.

or

- *Move* it over to the desktop to have it removed from the application overview.